Лабильные прилагательные
Любопытный мужчина // Интересующийся мужчина
Любопытный мужчина // Интересный мужчина

Видим, одно и то же прилагательное, имеет разные "залоги".
В случае с глаголами и причастиями это называется лабильностью (когда один и тот же глагол может быть и переходным и не переходным, не меняя смысла). Например
Кружащий вокруг дамы кавалер
Кружащий даму кавалер

Список лабильных глаголов совсем небольшой, где-то штук 10.

Приведите список лабильных прилагательных.
Сформулируйте четкое определение лабильного прилагательного.


Напишу общий набросок ответа, а далее видно будет.
В первую очередь, ясно, что интересный мужчина и галантный мужчина это два разных класса прилагательных. Надо будет на досуге полистать где-нибудь, что за классы и как они называются. Это сразу же даст ответ на пункт 2.
Во вторую очередь, придумывается такой тест на лабильное прилагательное
1. Мне он такой-то // Мне он любопытен
2. Он такой-то + ствующий // Он любопытствующий

Если прилагательное сможет удовлетворить сразу двум условиям, то оно лабильное.
Надо будет попробовать использовать чат GPT-4 для этой задачи, Это сразу же даст ответ на пункт 1.

В традиционный русской грамматике термин "Лабильность" применяется к глаголам.
И вообще ваши примеры не очень удачны, т.к. имеют разный смысл.
Любопытный мужчина и  Интересующийся мужчина, Любопытный мужчина // Интересный мужчина
имеют разное значение. Так что применять этот термин к прилагательным некорректно.

Кавалер кружит вокруг дамы и кавалер кружит даму - тоже разный смысл, да еще и предложения разные, не только смысл. Это не мешает лабильности глагола, а наоборот её необходимое условие. Точно так же разный смысл не мешает лабильности прилагательного, а наоборот её необходимое условие. Что касается терминологии, то термин применяется, только к глаголам. Применительно к прилагательным пускай он будет иметь другое определение я не возражаю, но название пусть будет то же, подчеркивающее некую глубинную общность.
